# How to add new typings on existing one

Tags: typescript, express

I am a beginner in typescript.  I am working with express and typescript and want to access `req.id` in a middleware

When i do so, i am getting this error

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'
```

The code i am using

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var log = logger.child(
    {
      id: req.id,
      body: req.body,
      params: req.params,
    },
    true
  );

  log.info({ req: req });
  next();
});
```

Currently i am suppressing typescript errors by `//@ts-ignore` comment

PS: Also it would be generous of you to help me understand how can i extend types in any module / package if I may run into same issue in future

Comment: What you want to do isn't really *extend* the type, it's to specify the generics.  It looks like `Request` takes 4 generic values and 2 of them have defaulted to `any` right now.  `interface Request<P = any, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = any>`.  That said, I am struggling with these particular types and can't figure out how to import `ParamsDictionary` or `ParsedQs`.

Comment: Actually it turns out you do need to extend the `global` `Express.Request` type because none of those 4 generics can be used to add top-level properties.  You can also use `as` inline to assert the type of `req`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I tried putting `as`, the issue is not resolved

Comment: `type IdRequest = Request & {id: number};` `id: (req as IdRequest).id,` does that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Linda for giving me a head start. I solved this by adding custom type stubs. This is called [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) in typescript

Create a file `types.d.ts` (file for module declaration)

```
import "express"; // needed to extend the type

declare module 'express' { 
  interface Request {
    id: string; // this will add new property of type string (access by `req.id`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The types for express are a real headache since there are multiple packages involved, but I finally figured out which one you need to extend.  We just need to declare the one property which we are adding because this definition will get merged with the existing definition rather than replacing it.

```
declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
    interface Request {
        id: number;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/vWk3jW)

This allows us to access `req.id` without issue.

Note that there is an error on calling `next()` as apparently `next` might be `undefined`.

Comment: It is overriding the existing type stubs